# Gzip a file in Java, Play Framework 2.2.1

Tags: java, gzip, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to Gzip a file for output in Play Framework 2.2.1, with Java.

This is not an asset, it is not a static file. For instance, it can be a user avatar which the user uploads. For example, a PNG image.

I've searched a for this and found only how to GZIP strings and that the Play Framework does automatic Gzipping for public assets, which this is not.

Some code I've tried:

```
public static Result userAvatar(long userId) throws IOException {
    UserAvatar avatar = UserAvatar.get(userId);

    InputStream avatarStream;
    Long version;

    // Use the default avatar.
    if (avatar == null) {
        avatarStream = Play.current().resourceAsStream("public/images/noavatar.png").get();
        version = 0L;
    } else {
        avatarStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(avatar.avatar);
        version = avatar.version;
    }

    byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(avatarStream);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(byteArray.length);
    OutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(outputStream);

    int len;
    while ((len = avatarStream.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
        gzip.write(byteArray, 0, len);
    }

    avatarStream.close();
    gzip.close();

    // The client has the correct image cached if the ETag matches
    String eTag = request().getHeader("If-None-Match");
    if (eTag != null && eTag.equals(version.toString())) {
        return status(NOT_MODIFIED, "Not modified");
    }

    response().setContentType("image/png");
    response().setHeader(ETAG, version.toString());
    return Results.ok(outputStream.toByteArray());
}
```

This did not work and google is only returning answers for gzipping strings. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Does not work in this case means the result was 0 bytes.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is but `Play` supports gzip out of the box: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/GzipEncoding

Comment: Please define *"does not work"*. Also, compressing images in JPEG/PNG/GIF format usually results in an archive slightly bigger than the original file, making it a usually-not-so-good idea.

Comment: @MonCalamari This appears to only affect static assets called via the Assets.at() method.

Comment: @Siguza I mean the response is just empty. 0 bytes.

Comment: Are you sure? In the link I posted, there is an example of gziping `text/html` responses. In `Global` object you can customize what is gzpied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`len` is bound to always be `0`.

In this line:

```
byte[] byteArray = IOUtils.toByteArray(avatarStream);
```

you read all of `avatarStream` - it is now empty, `0` bytes left.
And in this line:

```
while ((len = avatarStream.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
```

you check how much you can still read of it - which is `0` bytes.

Replace

```
int len;
while ((len = avatarStream.read(byteArray)) > 0) {
    gzip.write(byteArray, 0, len);
}
```

by just

```
gzip.write(byteArray);
```